# Run function 2 when function 1 completes

Tags: jquery

I know similar questions have been asked and answered before but the truth is I just cant figure out what I need to do even after reading them.

The code below is from a tutorial. It displays some text with a typewriter effect. 
That all works fine.

I've added an `_` that moves along in front of the text like a dos cursor.

I'm trying to make the _ blink after the typewriter animation has completed.

I know (or should I say "think") I need a callback to trigger makeBlink() but I can't for the life of me figure out where to use it.

Could somebody please help me out?

```
var char = 0;
var caption = "";

function showCaption(obj) {
    caption = obj.attr('title');
    if(caption)
        type();
}


function type() {
    $('#caption').html(caption.substr(0, char++));
    if(char < caption.length+1)
        setTimeout("type()", 150);
    else {
        char = 0;
        caption = "";
    }
}

function makeBlink(){
    $("#cursor").html('<blink>_</blink>');
}


$(window).load(function() {
    showCaption($("#caption_span"));
    makeBlink(); // This runs whilst the text is still typing :(
});
```

Comment: I am sad you use `<blink>` instead of `'_'.blink()`.

Comment: @Raynos is that sarcasm? '_'.blink() is just as bad, and sometimes sarcasm is hard to catch in one line internet posts, lol.

Comment: @PaulPRO yes that was sarcasm.

Comment: I'm assuming it's b/c the characters '_' themselves appear to be someone blinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `makeBlink();` from where you have it and insert it here:

```
function type() {
    $('#caption').html(caption.substr(0, char++));
    if(char < caption.length+1)
        setTimeout("type()", 150);
    else {
        char = 0;
        caption = "";
        makeBlink();
    }
}
```

PS. The HTML `<blink>` element is very old and not very supported. Even `text-decoration: blink` is hardly supported. It'd be better to use a javascript solution similar to the `type()` function you have. Something like:

```
function makeBlink(){
    var $cur = $('#cursor');
    if($cur.html())
        $cur.html('');
    else
        $cur.html('_');
    setTimeout(makeBlink, 500);
}
```

Or using css `display` or `visibility`.

Also you should change `"type()"` to `type` in your code to avoid using `eval`. (Never pass a string into setTimeout) Your tutorial is teaching you a bad practice there.

Comment: Thanks PaulPRO. Saved me a lot of head scratching!

Answer (score 1):

You would call makeBlink from the else branch in your type() function.

```
function type() {
    $('#caption').html(caption.substr(0, char++));
    if(char < caption.length+1)
        setTimeout("type()", 150);
    else {
        char = 0;
        caption = "";
        makeBlink();
    }
}
```

That would execute the `makeBlink()` function when you're done setting timers and done with the typing.  As you had it before, your `makeBlink()` function is getting called while you are still executing timers and still doing more typing.